# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object on line 7. I can't figure this out, why do I get this error?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Connected Successfully
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object on line 7. Why do I get this error? This is the start to a forum. I prepare with 'if ($query = $db->prepare($sql)).'

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","my_db") or die ("Could not connect to         database.");
echo 'Connected Successfully';

$sql = "SELECT forum_id, forum_name FROM forum_tbl";
if ($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
    $query->bind_result($f_id, $f_name);
    $query->execute();
    $query->store_result();
}else{
    echo $db->error;

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title>Forum</title>
<meta/>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
    <table align="center" width="80%">
        <?php
        if($query->num_rows !==0):
        while($row = $query->fetch()):?>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="forum.php?id=<?php echo $f_id?>"><?php echo $f_name;?>    </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; endif;?>    
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error tells you. You tried to invoke a method on something which isn't an object. `mysql_connect()` returns a resource identifier, not an object.

Comment: `mysql_connect` and `$db->prepare()` Are you kidding?

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated, not maintained anymore (for some time now...) and it will be marked as deprecated with 5.5. Use `PDO_MySQL`, or `MySQLi` instead. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up `mysql_connect` with PDO. Using PDO you get an object with which to use for queries, not so for `mysql_connect` which is deprecated anyhow!

So you are calling a method on something that is not an object. Assuming you have such constants (otherwise simply replace with the correct values) change your code to

```
$db = new PDO(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","my_db") or die ("Could not connect to database.");
```

to

```
try {
    $db = new PDO(mysql:dbname=my_db;host=127.0.0.1, "root","");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```